# Meta link in "how to ask" help page should point to meta stack overflow instead of meta stack exchange

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, help-center

In the end of the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, there is a link which is redirecting where we can discuss about the asking questions. The link is redirect to Meta Stack Exchange with asking-questions tag as below:

- [Meta discussions on asking questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asking-questions)

But it should be redirect to Meta Stack Overflow, since we have the asking-questions tag in MSO and questions about Stack Overflow can discuss in Meta Stack Overflow. So the link should be as below:

- [Meta discussions on asking questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asking-questions)

Can the link be corrected in the help page?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for the report. Somewhere in April '14 the link was changed by coincidence by the [Community user](/u/-1). It seems it was a migration script. Now the link points to MSO as it supposed to be.